# How to load all attribute value from xml

Tags: jquery, xml

This is my **arty.xml**:

```
<child_2 entity_id="2" value="Root" parent_id="1">
    <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
        <child_10066 entity_id="10066" value="Physical1" parent_id="4">
            <child_10067 entity_id="10067" value="Cricket" parent_id="10066">
                <child_10068 entity_id="10068" value="One Day" parent_id="10067"/>
            </child_10067>
        </child_10066>
        <child_10069 entity_id="10069" value="Test2" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_10070 entity_id="10070" value="Test3" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_10071 entity_id="10071" value="Test4" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_10072 entity_id="10072" value="Test5" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Physical" parent_id="4"/>
    </child_4>
</child_2>
```

This is my attempt to read it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<title>Using jQuery and XML to populate a drop-down box demo</title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "atry.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
    var select = $('#mySelect');

    $(xml).find('child_2').each(function(){
    $(this).find('child_4').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ value +"'>"+value+"</option>");
        });
    });
        select.children(":first").text("Select").attr("selected",true);
} //sucess close
}); 
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>    <div id="page-wrap">
<select id="mySelect">
<option>loading</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I am trying to load all attribute value and create select list...

But problem is I am not getting all the child values...

Help me out of this...

Answer (score 1):

hi i tested in my local it's working fine

may be your problem is you are using $(this).attr('value');

so you can try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "atry.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
        var select = $('#mySelect');

         $(xml).find('child_2').each(function(){
         var value = $(this).find('child_4').attr('value');
         select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ value +"'>"+value+"</option>");
          });
});
```

Comment: its only return `Activities`. i want all like `Activities Physical1 Cricket One Day Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5 Physical.`

Comment: hey Jack i have added new answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738671/how-to-load-all-attribute-value-from-xml/15739556#15739556

please check it ,i think it's help for you .

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have to loop through again, you can try with this:

```
$(xml).find('child_2').each(function(){
   $(this).find('child_4').children().find('[entity_id]').each(function(){
       var value = $(this).attr('value');
       select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ value +"'>"+value+"</option>");
   });
});
```

Comment: i think you are not getting my exact Que. i want all attribute value where child_4 element close. like :- `Activities Physical1 Cricket One Day Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5 Physical`

Comment: `$(this).find('child_4').children().find('[entity_id]').each(function(){` try with this one as suggested in the answer.

Comment: ohhh yes its return only child_4 child but i want to all child_10069 child_10070 child_10071 child_10072... thanks for this help jay

Answer (score 0):

you can get all child tag value like this .

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("xml").find('child_2').each(function(){
        $(this).children().map(function(){
            $("#mySelect").append("<option class='ddindent' >"+$(this).attr('value')+"</option>");

            var tag = this.tagName;

            $(tag).children().map(function(){
                //alert("alert : " + this.tagName + " value : " + $(this).attr("value"));
                $("#mySelect").append("<option class='ddindent' >"+$(this).attr('value')+"</option>");
            });
            });
        });
            //select.children(":first").text("Select").attr("selected",true);
    } //sucess close

    ); 
    </script>
```

hope it's help for you :)

Comment: can you add full code... b'coz i have some problem in my system to load value....